# Python scraping response data

Tags: python, web-scraping

i would like to take the response data about a specific website.
I have this site:
https://enjoy.eni.com/it/milano/map/
and if i open the browser debuger console i can see a posr request that give a json response:

[image: response image]

how in python i can take this response by scraping the website?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the webservice has a `PHPSESSID` validation so we need to get it first using proper user agent:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get('https://enjoy.eni.com/it/milano/map/', headers=headers)
session_id = r.cookies['PHPSESSID']
headers['Cookie'] = 'PHPSESSID={};'.format(session_id)
res = requests.post('https://enjoy.eni.com/ajax/retrieve_vehicles', headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
json_obj = json.loads(res.content)
```

Comment: Hi Yohanes. Yes i have just try with PHPSESSID of my browser and works. But i have also try to retrive this value by  CookieLib but after retrive this value if i pass it on request the respons eis html of website and not json

Comment: @APPGIS got it. I have updated my answer. Apparently we just need to add `User-Agent` on the first request to get proper cookie